# Find and sort topologically all trees including a given group of nodes from a dependency graph

Tags: ruby, topological-sort

Assume I have the following graph of dependencies ( `A => [B]` means A depends/requires B to update its value before the value of A can be updated). I am using a Ruby hash and the TSort module for topological operations.

```
graph = {
  a: OpenStruct.new(dependencies: []),
  b: OpenStruct.new(dependencies: [:a]),
  c: OpenStruct.new(dependencies: [:b]),
  d: OpenStruct.new(dependencies: []),
  e: OpenStruct.new(dependencies: [:d]),
  f: OpenStruct.new(dependencies: []),
}
# Which gives 3 dependency trees
:c => :b => :a, :e => :d, :f
```

Given any group of nodes, I need to find and sort topologically the nodes that need to be updated, including (recursively) the parents and children of this group of nodes. That is, all the dependency trees that include those nodes, and not just the dependencies up to those nodes in the trees.

Here are some examples (regarding the output, I can cope with either an array of TSorted graphs, or just a flattened version, I don't care, cf example 3) *but the array of tsorted graphs is easier to spec as you'll see below.*

```
desired_function(:a) == [:c,:b,:a] # or [[:c,:b,:a]]
desired_function(:b) == [:c,:b,:a] # or [[:c,:b,:a]]
desired_function(:c) == [:c,:b,:a] # or [[:c,:b,:a]]
desired_function(:c,:d) == [:c,:b,:a,:d,:e] # or [:d,:e,:c,:b,:a] or [[:d,:e], [:c,:b,:a]], or [[:c,:b,:a], [:d,:e]]
desired_function(:f) == [:f] # or [[:f]]
```

I have tried implementing a TSort algorithm, but I'm  not sure how I can specify that I also need to include the parents of the node I am requesting the tsort from

My current implementation (on the `graph` given above)

```rb
def incomplete_function_to_get_tsorted_subgraphs(graph, node_names) 
  each_node = lambda { |&b| graph.slice(*node_names).each_key(&b) }
  each_child = lambda do |node_name, &b|
    graph[node_name].dependencies.each(&b)
  end
  TSort.tsort(each_node, each_child)
end
```

It is incomplete as currently it will only get dependencies up to the requested nodes `incomplete_function_to_get_tsorted_subgraphs(graph, :b) # returns [:a, :b] instead of [:a,:b,:c]` If I remove the `slice` then it just becomes a tsort on the full graph which isn't what I want (and I would need to prune it somehow)

The specs for what I want to achieve (assuming we are returning arrays of tsorted dependency graphs)

```rb
expect(complete_function_to_get_tsorted_subgraphs(:b)).to include([:a,:b,:c])

expect(complete_function_to_get_tsorted_subgraphs(:b,:d).to 
  include([:a,:b,:c], [:d, :e])
```

Am I going the right way with using the TSort algorithm, and can you help me fix my function, or do I have to go a totally different path to get what I want ?

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We need the minimal code example, minimal input data to test it and the expected results.

Comment: @theTinMan help me understand if this is not enough, but there are code examples with expected results in my question

Comment: The "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" document specifically says "Make sure all information necessary to reproduce the problem is included in the question itself". That means it's runnable, demonstrates the problem and we don't have to put together a test harness because you've supplied the input and your expected results and what went wrong. The more code we have to write just to try to get your code to run, the further from your example code we get, reducing the accuracy and conciseness of the answer. If we ran your code what would happen?

Comment: I have made light edits to add the missing closing parenthesis in the graph definition and changed the interface of my function to take the graph as the first parameter, so that you can indeed just copy paste the code in an irb terminal (the definition of the graph + the function) and running `incomplete_function_to_get_tsorted_subgraphs(graph, :b) `will work.

Comment: Excellent. It's important the code run otherwise questions are off-topic due to syntax errors or not including code that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing :

From the stat I need to compute, always go up to the leaf nodes with the most dependencies (so if I need to compute :b, always assume you need find :c) with a function like this (the implementation can most likely be improved)

```
def find_leaf_nodes(node_name)
  parents = all_nodes.select { |_,node| node.dependencies.include?(name) }
  if parents.any?
    parents.flat_map { |parent_name, _| find_leaf_nodes(parent_name) }
  else
    name
  end
end
```

And then just build the TSorted dependency list from here using the code I mentioned in the question